# Is there a way to obtain the actual A1 range from sheetfu - get_data_range()

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to obtain the actual A1 values using the Sheetfu library's **get_data_range()**.

When I use the code below, it works perfectly, and I get what I would expect.

```
invoice_sheet = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('Invoice')
invoice_data_range = invoice_sheet.get_data_range()
invoice_values = invoice_data_range.get_values()
print(invoice_data_range)
print(invoice_values)
```

From the print() statements I get:

```
<Range object Invoice!A1:Q42>
[['2019-001', '01/01/2019', 'Services']...] #cut for brevity
```

What is the best way to get that "A1:Q42" value?  I really only want the end of the range (Q42), because I need to build the **get_range_from_a1()** argument "A4:Q14".  My sheet has known headers (rows 1-3), and the **get_values()** includes 3 rows that I don't want in the **get_values()** list.

I guess I could do some string manipulation to pull out the text between the ":" and ">" in

```
<Range object Invoice!A1:Q42>
```

...but that seems a bit sloppy.

As a quick aside, it would be fantastic to be able to call **get_data_range()** like so:

```
invoice_sheet = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('Invoice')
invoice_data_range = invoice_sheet.get_data_range(start="A4", end="")
invoice_values = invoice_data_range.get_values()
```

...but that's more like a feature request.  (Which I'm happy to do BTW).

Answer (score 2):

Author here. Alan answers it well.
I added some methods at Range level to the library, that are simply shortcuts to the coordinates properties.

```py
from sheetfu import SpreadsheetApp

spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp("....access_file.json").open_by_id('long_string_id')
sheet = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('test')
data_range = sheet.get_data_range()

starting_row = data_range.get_row()
starting_column = data_range.get_column()
max_row = data_range.get_max_row()
max_column = data_range.get_max_column()
```

This will effectively tell you the max row and max column that contains data in your sheet.

If you use the `get_data_range` method, the first row and first column typically is 1.

Answer (score 1):

I received a response from the owner of [Sheetfu](https://github.com/socialpoint-labs/sheetfu/issues/29), and the following code provides the information that I'm looking for.
Example code:

```
from sheetfu import SpreadsheetApp

spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp("....access_file.json").open_by_id('long_string_id')
sheet = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('test')
data_range = sheet.get_data_range()

range_max_row = data_range.coordinates.row + data_range.coordinates.number_of_rows - 1
range_max_column = data_range.coordinates.column + data_range.coordinates.number_of_columns - 1
```

As of this writing, the **.coordinates** properties are not currently documented, but they are usable, and should be officially documented within the next couple of weeks.